# Stack Exchange Cookies Customize Settings Fails on Firefox on Raspberry Pi

Tags: support, firefox, cookies

Unable to remove privacy popup without clicking 'Accept all cookies', which seems like it will work ('Customize settings' does nothing).

For this system, this forces me to accept all cookies which is undesirable.

System = Model 3B Stretch. Firefox version unknown.